# How to add a TrueType font file to a pyinstaller executable for use with Pygame?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a python file named breakout.py and want to create an exe with pyinstaller. The python file requires the file ARCADECLASSIC.TTF in the same directory as the python script in order to run. Also I want to be able to run the exe file without having to have the font file aswell. I have tried multiple pyinstaller commands to try to do this.

I tried this command `pyinstaller --add-binary "ARCADECLASSIC.TTF;." --onefile breakout.py` and recieved a permission denied error number 13.

Then I tryed editing my code so that the font file would be inside a directory called fonts and tried this command `pyinstaller --add-binary "fonts/ARCADECLASSIC.TTF;fonts" --onefile breakout.py` which ran with no errors but when I ran the exe file an error came saying there is no file named fonts/ARCADECLASSIC.TTF so crashed.

I have now also tried specifying the full directory of the font file and it still doesn't work.

In case this helps my OS is Windows and I am using python 3.8.5 64 bit with pyinstaller 4.0.

Firstly is what I am trying to do possible and secondly if it is possible how do I do it and what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a .spec file and mention what you will want to include in it like font or other images.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['your python file.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\path\\to\\directory'], # just the directory not the file
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('ttf file','path\\to\\ttf\\file', "DATA")]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='Your App Name',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False # set True if command prompt window needed
)
```

in your actual python file where the game is include this.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

whenever you want to load your font do it like this.

```
font = pygame.font.Font(resource_path("Font.ttf"), size)
```

after you have that in the your main python file, in your terminal type in this with the spec file you created.

```
pyinstaller yourspecfile.spec
```

this will create your executable file and it should work by itself.

this is what my spec file looks like from my previous project
# -*- mode: python -*-

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['lol.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\games\\snake'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('8min.ttf','C:\\games\\snake\\8min.ttf', "DATA")]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='Snake',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False)
```

Comment: I will try this out and tell you if it works but do I need to create the spec file myself or do I generate it with pyinstaller?

Comment: You have to create a spec file yourself. You can do this by creating a txt file with notepad or something else and just rename the file type to .spec. You can also do this with any IDE like PyCharm or Visual Studio

Comment: I tried using a spec file like yours and I got permission denied error 13 after this line in the output. 89519 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg

Comment: I think what I might be getting wrong is this line in the spec file. a.datas += [('ttf file','path\\to\\ttf\\file', "DATA")] Is the path to file the absolute path or relative path because I tried it with absolute path if I am meant to use the relative path what would it be because the font file is in the same directory as the python file.

Comment: Are your font files in a folder? if so pyinstaller will not be able to detect the file. One problem could be: a.datas += [('fontfile.ttf', 'C:\\path\\to\\file.ttf', 'DATA')]. I just added .ttf after the file

Comment: I added the name of the file on the end and it now works. Thank You for helping me.